# What is the easiest way to scatter plot a set of grade in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am developing a program to show the results of a study. Thirty high school students were surveyed in a study involving time spent on the Internet and their grade point average (GPA). The results are shown in Table 13.1. X is the amount of time spent on the Internet weekly and Y is the GPA of the student.

Given the data:

[image]

Use Python to do the following:

(a) Make a scatter plot of the data.
(b) Fit a straight line to the data and give the values of ao and a1.

I did this manually with pen and paper. I am looking for a simple two to three-liner for this.

Comment: Seaborn. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html Posting your actual data would make it easier to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Author: Evan Gertis
# Date  : 11/09
# program: Linear Regression
# Resource: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html       
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Step 1: load the data
grades = pd.read_csv("grades.csv") 
logging.info(grades.head())

# Step 2: plot the data
plot = sns.scatterplot(data=grades, x="Hours", y="GPA")
fig = plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("out.png")
```